# How to search all GitHub repositories for SHA?

Tags: github

Is there a way to find all repositories on github that contain a given commit (given its SHA)?

I can find easily check if a given commit exists in a known repository by checking the existence of

```
https://github.com/${USER}/${REPO}/commit/${SHA}
```

...but what if I don't know the repo-slug?

Doing a simple search on SHAs (via the webinterface) doesn't return anything.

Comment: Probability of two commits to different repositories having same SHA is not ZERO. 
Though I don't know how SHAs are generated in `Git`, probably by design two commits to one repository can't have same SHA. 
And this search `https://github.com/${USER}/${REPO}/commit/${SHA}`
works for partial SHA's as well (at least starting 7 characters of commit SHA). That again increases probability of having same partial SHA for two different repositories.
In case of SHA collision, then a `URL` like `https://github.com/${USER}/commit/${SHA}`
would point to two different commits.

Comment: @Narendra so what is the problem? i would still like to find all commits of a given SHA (whether they are actually the same commit, can easily be evaluated once you *have* the commits)